# cycle in gnuplot - different folder

Tags: gnuplot

How to use this command in gnuplot? One figure is created but then this figure is read as data file and it leads to error.

```
j=0;do for [i in system("ls")] { j=j+1; set term png; set output ''.i.'.png' ; p i w p lc rgb "navy" t ''.i }
```

I also tried:

```
j=0;do for [i in system (/media/)] { j=j+1; set term png; set output ''.i.'.png' ; p i w p lc rgb "navy" t ''.i }
```

but it is invalid expression. How to set different folder for the outputs?

Or how to plot all data in a directory to various figures? Is is possible to use for file something like *.r in gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, based on used commands, your question is under Linux, the logical is the same under Windows. Below follows an example.
Suppose there are five folders (`folder01` to `folder05`) each one containing a single `.txt` file (`file01.txt`, ... , `file 05.txt`).

The follow script must be on parent directory, i.e., the folder which contains the other folders.

```
set terminal pngcairo

# Under Windows, it saves the all .txt filenames.
# The search includes all subdirectories.
files = system("dir /b /s *.txt")

# Individual png files
do for [file in files]{
    set output file[:strlen(file)-4] . '.png'
    plot file u 1:2 w lp pt 6 pi -1 t file
}

# OR

# All files together
set key Left left reverse
set out "all_plots.png"
plot for [file in files] file u 1:2 w lp pt 6 pi -1 t file
```

The results from individual plots (as thumbnails):

[image][image]
[image][image][image]

The results from all plots together:

[image: all plots together]

Comment: Thank you very much and when I have all files for plotting in one directory? What does dir /b /s  in the part `system("dir /b /s *.txt")` mean, please?

Comment: It mean: under actual directory (`dir`) and their subdirectories (`/s`), search for all .txt files (`*.txt`) and show results on basic (`/b`) mode. For one directory case, just use `dir /b *.txt`.

Comment: And when the script.gnu is in the same directory, it should be `system("*.b")`? I got an error `sh: 1: BAb02-14.b: not found` and /b gives error as well  (directory does not exist)

Comment: I know nothing about system commands under linux. Maybe something like `system("ls *.b")`!?

Comment: Did you achieve your goal? If this answer did help you, mark it as answered to help others.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/217746) can be helpful.

Comment: Why is this file BAb02-14.b is not found when it read its name?